# CSS: How to make two items in a column take up the same space, at most, but if one item is smaller than the other, make the other one grow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a pretty basic CSS problem I'm trying to solve: I have two divs, A & B, inside another div, "Parent". A is on top of B.

If A has content, make it grow. B will at least 50% height of the parent div. A will grow until it takes an even amount of space as B. A can't grow more than B; if A's content overflows, make it scrollable.

I am trying to accomplish this flexbox but am not able to figure it out. Assigning `flex:none` and `max-height: 50%` to A and `flex: 1 1 0` to B causes A to grow much larger than B if A has a lot of content.

Answer (score 1):

Does this achieve what you are looking for? Change the `height` value of `.content` to see how the containers resize in response.

The key line is in the `.b` class, where we set the rule `flex: 1 0 50%`. This means:

1. Start from a height or `flex-basis` of 50% of the container.
2. Grow up by a factor of 1. The other flex item does not have a `flex-grow` property so this essentially translates to 'fill the rest of the container'.
3. Do not shrink down below the `flex-basis` of 50%.

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.a {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 50%;
  background-color: slateblue;
  overflow: auto;
}

.b {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1 0 50%;
  background-color: crimson;
}

.content {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lemonchiffon;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="a">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```